# Yoda Conditions and integer promotion

Tags: c, integer-promotion

When comparing a type larger than `int`, with an integer constant, should I place the constant on the left or the right to ensure the correct comparison is performed?

```
int64_t i = some_val;
if (i == -1)
```

or should it be:

```
if (-1 == i)
```

Are there any circumstances in which either case is not identical to comparison with `-1LL` (where `int64_t` is `long long`)?

Comment: a great tag Yoda was :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you put it on the right hand side or the left hand side; the `==` operator is completely symmetrical.

If both operands to the `==` operator have arithmetic type, as in this case, then the "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied (C99 §6.5.9).  In this case, the rule that applies is:

> If both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank. (C99 §6.3.1.8)

So the -1 is converted to `int64_t`.  `-1LL` makes no difference.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: In addition to the answer: The usual reason for putting the constant first is to help catch typos: If you mistyped `==` as `=`, then the compiler will complain that you can't assign to a constant. The other way around (constant on the right hand side), a complaint from the compiler is not guaranteed.