# Difference between "true == isset($variable)" and "isset($variable) == true" in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I was just wandering the about the concept of equating the condition in PHP that is,

what could be the difference between

```
true == isset($variable)
```

and

```
isset($variable) == true
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific case, no difference.

The first syntax is used to prevent accidental assignment instead of comparison.

```
if ( true = $x ) // would yiled error
if ( $x = true ) // would work
```

But again, in your case, no difference.

Elaboration:

Say you want to compare a variable `$x` to `true` and do something. You could accidentally write

```
if ( $x = true )
```

instead of

```
if ( $x == true )
```

and the condition would always pass.

But if you get into the habit of writing

```
if ( true == $x )
```

these mistakes wouldn't happen, since a syntax error would be generated and you would know in advance.

Comment: Can u please elaborate @Luchian

Comment: But Here I am comparing it, not assigning

Comment: The idea is to prevent *accidental* assignment. See 'Yoda conditions' here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757941/yoda-conditions-and-integer-promotion

Comment: Great Clarification I Have Upvoted it, I Have not Downvoted it..THanks

Comment: hmmm, never really thought of doing that to prevent accidental assignment. I always just think it looks odd, less readable code if your just quickly scanning through a document. +1 for the explanation though as I see this in other people's code quite a bit and never understood why they'd do it the wrong way round (in a logical sense).

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. But `isset()` itself returns a boolean value.

**So never use**

```
if (true == isset($variable))
```

Just:

```
if (isset($variable))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when php parses that true is actually defined and its equal to 1. Furthermore so is false and it is equal to 0. php automatically checks these for comparison with these values in an IF statement. You'll be safe using the ! operator, because its the same as if ($something == false) good luck!

Answer (score -1):

There is no "real" diffrences(in this case)
**Between** 
`true == isset($variable)`  
AND

```
 isset($variable) == true
```

Comment: You don't say?! Those lines are exactly identical, so obviously there is no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Would it be Java, there was difference.

i.e.

```
  String test = null;
  if("".equals(test)){
    System.out.println("I m fine..");
  }
  if(test.equals("")){
    System.out.println("I m not fine..");
  }
```

Comment: Is this relevant over here Mate?