# Advantage to a certain string comparison order

Tags: programming-languages

Looking at some pieces of code around the internet, I've noticed some authors tend to write string comparisons like

```
if("String"==$variable)
```

in PHP, or

```
if("String".equals(variable))
```

Whereas my preference is:

```
if(variable.equals("String"))
```

I realize these are effectively equal: they compare two strings for equality. But I was curious if there was an advantage to one over the other in terms of performance or something else.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example to the approach of using an equality function or using `if( constant == variable )` rather than `if( variable == constant )` is that it prevents you from accidentally typoing and writing an assignment instead of a comparison, for instance:

```
if( s = "test" )
```

Will assign `"test"` to `s`, which will result in undesired behaviour which may potentially cause a hard-to-find bug. However:

```
if( "test" = s )
```

Will in most languages (that I'm aware of) result in some form of warning or compiler error, helping to avoid a bug later on.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple `int` example, this prevents accidental writes of

```
if (a=5)
```

which would be a compile error if written as

```
if (5=a)
```

I sure don't know about *all* languages, but decent C compilers warn you about `if (a=b)`. Perhaps whatever language your question is written in doesn't have such a feature, so to be able to generate an error in such a case, they have reverted the order of the comparison arguments.

[Yoda conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3757941/912144) call these some.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of syntaxis a language uses has nothing to do with efficiency. It is all about how the comparison algorithm works.

In the examples you mentioned, this:

```
if("String".equals(variable))
```

and this:

```
if(variable.equals("String"))
```

would be exactly the same, because the expression "String" will be treated as a String variable.

Languages that provide a comparison method for Strings, will use the fastest method so you shouldn't care about it, unless you want to implement the method yourself ;)